# Is there any significance to the 1500, 1800 and 2100 clocks being much wider than the others?

Tags: the-sprawl, clocks

The 1500, 1800 and 2100 clocks are always represented as larger than the other clocks, what is the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### They look significant in order to look significant.

Mechanically, there isn't anything different between taking 3-harm to go from 1200 to 2100 and taking a further 3-harm to go from 2100 to 0000 and <del>buy the farm</del> acquire agricultural property. There isn't some extra barrier you have to jump over to do the 3-harm and no particular additional ease or resistance on any player's part in taking it.

It's just 3 out of 6 hit points.

And the difference between 3 out of 6 hit points that looks like this:

```
(---) (---) (---) (   ) (   ) (   )
```

and 3 out of 6 hit points that looks like this:

```
(------) (------) (------) () () ()
```

is that the latter looks way more significant to the part of you that's still three years old and thinks you get more water in a tall thin glass. Oh no the big ones are all gone and I've just got the littlies! I'd better be careful! Things are looking bad! I'm half-dead!

### They make half-dead, in the literal sense, feel like half-dead, in the figurative sense.

In addition to being potentially one hit from death now, when you weren't before, some countdowns will also have some significant lingering drawbacks if you let them get this far. Harm won't heal on its own. Suspicion will have heavy repercussions. Legwork has gone on long enough to put your payout at risk.

You can still take one more hit. Nothing more is happening right now... but something significant will happen later. So something more than just 3 hit points has happened to you.

Comment: That's what I was wondering!

Answer (score 16):

Yes, their sizes are *all* significant: they’re proportional to the time from noon. The 15:00, 18:00, and 21:00 divisions are each 3 hours long; the 22:00, 23:00, and 00:00 clock divisions are each an hour long.

This dates to Apocalypse World, which has round countdown clocks:

[image: An AW style countdown clock: a circle divided into quarters, marked 12 at the top, 3 at right, 6 at bottom, 9 at left. The quarter between 9 and 12 is further subdivided into three segments.]

The concept of a countdown clock is derived from the Nuclear Countdown Clock a.k.a. [Doomsday Clock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock), which was used in the real world a lot during the Cold War, and was always mere minutes from midnight (representing imminent potential for worldwide nuclear apocalypse):

[image: A history of the Doomsday Clock's settings, by year. There are the settings for sixteen historical events listed. For example, “1989: Berlin wall falls” is set to 10 minutes to midnight, while “1953: US tests first hydrogen bomb” is set to 2 minutes to midnight.]

So, the first three quarters of the AW and The Spawl countdown clocks are where things go from fine to bad-but-not-too-bad, but just like the Doomsday Clock, it’s the last quarter closer to midnight that represents “oh no really bad”, and needs finer divisions. That’s why there are three divisions right before midnight instead of just one.

Basically, the bigger clock spaces are least alarming. Once you have to fill in the tinier clock spaces that are alarmingly close to 00:00, you need to be worried. A countdown clock, like the Doomsday clock, represents [“the urgency of the problem”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock).

Comment: Nice, but are each of these boxes still a single unit checkoff? Ie there's only one tickmark/change required to fill/pass the 1500 as well as the 2300?